# BusinessObjects Tree Structure as in Pivot Table

Tags: business-objects

Is it possible in BusinessOjects 4.1. to implement tree structure that should function as the tree structure in MS Excel Pivot table?
If that is not possible, is there any alternative?
Backround story ist - I have a hierarchy and the user wants to have a tree structure (the user was not happy with drill up/down BO functions)

Answer (score 1):

This is assuming you're working in Web Intelligence.

You could use **breaks** for a visual indication of the structure and combine this with **outlines** to allow the user to fold and unfold at different break levels. This would work if the hierarchy you're referring to consists of different dimension objects (which I think it does judging from your question).

For more information, have a look at the [SAP BusinessObjects Web Intelligence Users Guide](http://help.sap.com/businessobject/product_guides/sbo41/en/sbo41sp3_webi_user_guide_en.pdf); section 4.2.3.2 deals with breaks while the outline functionality is discussed in section 4.1.4.